# Why Separable Metric Space is called Separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A formal definition can be found at page 48 of 
"Kolmogorov, A. N., Fomin, S. V. (1970). Introductory Real Analysis, Translated and Edited by Richard A. Silverman"

But where is a separate procedure?
I do not see the "separation" procedure in my imagination.

p.s.  In my imagination, I have a bounded table R with too many needles that they enough to very-very near to touch all points in original set R. But it's only my imagination.